# How to prove uniqueness of a function in Coq given a specification?

Tags: functional-programming, coq

Given a specification of a function, e.g., `specification_of_sum`, how do I prove in Coq that only one such function exists?

I am studying mathematics, and I could prove this in hand, but my skills in Coq are limited (proving using `rewrite` and `apply`).

I found the code snippet below, which I've been struggling with for some time now.

I try to unfold the specification in the proof, but using my old friend `rewrite` doesn't seem to let me go further.

Can someone explain how to approach this problem using simple syntax?

```
Definition specification_of_sum (sum : (nat -> nat) -> nat -> nat) :=
  forall f : nat -> nat,
    sum f 0 = f 0
    /\
    forall n' : nat,
      sum f (S n') = sum f n' + f (S n').

(* ********** *)

Theorem there_is_only_one_sum :
  forall sum1 sum2 : (nat -> nat) -> nat -> nat,
    specification_of_sum sum1 ->
    specification_of_sum sum2 ->
    forall (f : nat -> nat)
           (n : nat),
      sum1 f n = sum2 f n.
Proof.  
Abort.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following start is essentially as ejgallego already described.

```
intros sum1 sum2 H1 H2 f n. (* introduce all the hypotheses *)                                     
unfold specification_of_sum in *. (* unfold definition in all places *)                            
specialize H1 with (f := f). (* narrow statement to be about f *)                                  
specialize H2 with (f := f). (* narrow statement to be about f *)                                  
inversion_clear H1.  (* split up the AND statements *)                                             
inversion_clear H2.                                                                                
(* induction on n, and do rewrites *)
```

I have included a few more basic commands to make it slower but simpler. The rest of the proof only requires `rewrite` and `reflexivity`.

Comment: Thanks, this was needed to kickstart my proof :-)

Comment: Is it possible to substitute inversion_clear with "simpler" things?

Comment: Indeed inversion clear is not the proper way to process the hypotheses, you have the correct way (intro patterns) in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prove this using induction on `n`. Think of it, your specification covers the cases for `0` and `n.+1`, thus it is natural to use induction.

You can read about induction in basically the Coq book of your choice.

An example on how to use your specification is:

```
intros sum1 sum2 s1_spec s2_spec f n.
specialize (s1_spec f) as [s1_spec0 s1_specS].
specialize (s2_spec f) as [s2_spec0 s2_specS].
```

Comment: But I can't find the syntax to use the specification. How do I rewrite with it or apply it? Can you show me?

Comment: I suggest you use `specialize (spec1 f)`, where `spec1` is the specification for `sum1`. You could also do `unfold specification_of_sum in spec1`, but that is not needed, definitions are usually expanded automatically in Coq.